# What is the purpose of nonce and hmac in a session cookie?

Tags: session, cookies, csrf, hmac, nonce

I am looking at some code, and they are storing a "nonce" and a "hmac" in a users session cookie. What is the purpose of a nonce? What is the purpose of the hmac?

Answer (score 4):

The **HMAC** (Hash-based Message Authentication Code) is a cryptographic Hash of the actual data of the cookie. So that the server can verify the data hasn’t been tampered with.

The **Nonce** (Number used once) is most likely used to encrypt the data of the cookie. Usually, when you encrypt something, you don’t want the ciphertext to be the same for identical plain messages. So you use the static encryption key in conjunction with a random Nonce changing on every encryption.